# Python thread safe singleton stuck when used

Tags: python, multithreading, singleton

I tried to implement a thread safe singleton for my python code. I tried these 2 pieces of code but both of them get stuck when the class with the metaclass of the Singleton is being called from my unittests.

1 (check-lock-check):

```
import functools
import threading
from typing import Callable


def synchronized(thread_lock: threading.Lock):
    """ Synchronization decorator """

    def wrapper(function: Callable):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def inner_wrapper(*args: list, **kw: dict):
            with thread_lock:
                return function(*args, **kw)

        return inner_wrapper

    return wrapper


class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    _lock = threading.Lock()

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._locked_call(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

    @synchronized(_lock)
    def _locked_call(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

2 (simple lock):

```
from threading import Lock


class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    _lock: Lock = Lock()

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            with cls._lock:
                instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
                cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

Does someone know why my code get stuck on this implementation when I run it locally (for unittests for example)? Because once the app is deployed it's actually uses multithreading everything is fine.

And do you have suggestions for something else that could work with what I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that

```
if cls not in cls._instances:
```

has to be within the lock block. One thread could determine that the instance has not yet been assigned while another is in the middle of assigning it.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly I tried it and it still does not work when I run this locally...